# List all the closed and unbounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

As an exercise for my calc 1 class, I need to list all the possible closed and unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

My list contains so far:

1. $\mathbb{R}$;
2. $[a, +\infty)$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$;
3. $(-\infty, b]$ with $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Actually, I can not find some more examples. Could someone please help me in finding them?

Moreover, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ should be in the list?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the question isn't asking you to list the closed unbounded *intervals*? (Rather than general subsets)

Comment: @Sambo I remember it was about subsets.

Comment: Here are 2 examples of closed unbounded subsets that aren't on your list (but aren't intervals): $\mathbb{Z}$, and $[0,1]\cup [2,\infty)$.

Comment: @Sambo thank you for your comment. If the question had been about intervals, is that all it would be?

Comment: Yes, your list contains all closed unbounded intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be very complicated. For instance, the Cantor set $C \subseteq [0,1]$ is closed, and describing it is quite complicated (to make it unbounded, just consider its union with $[1,\infty)$).

There are alternative ways to describe the collection of closed unbounded subsets, but none of them are really much simpler than just saying "closed unbounded subsets". I wouldn't consider it possible to make a "list" of them in any meaningful sense, and this is certainly beyond the level of a Calc 1 class.

However, if you meant to just consider the closed unbounded *intervals*, then your list is complete.